# my audio reverse code for CS50 is not working

Tags: c, reverse, cs50

I'm trying to write a code for an audio reverse filter that would reverse audio wav files for cs50 course (new to programming). I managed to complete the whole task and tried it on an input file and sound reversed to me however the check50 function states that my file wasn't properly reversed. It's hard for me to spot the problem when I don't know what the problem is.

I just kept reading through the code and couldn't find a specific problem. I tried reversing my output file and it sounds exactly as same as the input file.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "wav.h"


int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    // Check command-line arguments
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./reverse input.wav output.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2
    // “read-only” mode
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    // Read header
    // TODO #3
    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, input);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4
    if (!check_format(header))
    {
        printf("Not a WAV file.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5
    // write mode
    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, output);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int size = get_block_size(header);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8
    BYTE buffer[size];
    if (fseek(input, size, SEEK_END))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while (ftell(input) - size > sizeof(header))
    {
        if (fseek(input, - 2 * size, SEEK_CUR))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        fread(buffer, size, 1, input);
        fwrite(buffer, size, 1, output);
    }

    fclose(output);
    fclose(input);

}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    if (header.format[0] == 'W' && header.format[1] == 'A' && header.format[2] == 'V' && header.format[3] == 'E')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    int size = header.numChannels * header.bitsPerSample/8;
    return size;
}
```

I was hoping anyone would be able to spot an obvious problem that I'm missing.

Comment: Open the files in binary mode with `"rb"` and `"wb"`. On a Windows system this will make a difference. The default mode is text, which will alter the data if it looks like a line ending.

Comment: The first iteration will read the wrong record: it will skip the last record in the file.

Comment: I have been changed "r" and "w" to "rb" and "wb", but it still not work.

Comment: ... so I would begin with `fseek(input, -size, SEEK_CUR)` *before* the loop begins, and adjust what the loop is doing. Or you could replace `-2` with a variable which is initially `-1` but is set to `-2` in the loop.

Comment: Maybe the test cases for cs50 are fixed, but wav file header sizes can vary.

Comment: "I tried reversing my output file and it sounds exactly as same as the input file."  That's a good test!  But it isn't exact.  An error of just an audio sample or two might be inaudible but will be noticed by the check program.  A hex editor (or a "hex dump") is a tool that can show you exactly how those two files differ.  That might help you to find the problem.